# How to get JSON from excel file react native

Tags: javascript, json, excel, react-native

No response from the following code,the excel file conversion is done with the help of the folowing

```
  const readExcel = (file) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    const bufferArray = e.target.result;

    const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });

    const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];

    const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];

    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

    resolve(data);
  };

  fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
    reject(error);
  };
});

promise.then((d) => {
  setItems(d);
});
};
```

the result is Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented and then the document picker is added and the uri is obtained, then the following is

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
      var pickerResult=DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
 type: [DocumentPicker.types.xlsx],
 })
  console.log(pickerResult.uri)
    }}
  style={{position: 'absolute',bottom:16,right:16 }}>
  <Text style={{fontFamily: "Montserrat-SemiBold",fontSize: 18,color:'#00c2cb'}}>Bulk 
 Upload</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears [FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Blob/FileReader.js#L83-L85).

There's a [(closed) Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21209) that has a [possible workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21209#issuecomment-495294672).